# Input in another component, error with target

Tags: reactjs

Want to simplify my component, and want the search bar in another component to be more easy to read the code. And I have problems with target. I'm new in React...

```js
export class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this)
    }    
    render () {
        return (
            <input 
                className='SearchBar' 
                type='text'
                placeholder='Search movies...' 
                onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ''} 
                onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = 'Search movies...'}
                onChange={()=>this.props.updateInput(this.handleUserInput())}
                value={this.props.userInput}
            />
        )
    }
    handleUserInput(e) {
        return(e.target.value)
    }
}
```

and the component where is it

```js
<SearchBar value={this.state.userInput} updateInput={this.updateInput}/>

updateInput = (value) => {
    this.setState({userInput:value})
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't passed the `event` to your `handleUserInput` function.

```
onChange={()=>this.props.updateInput(this.handleUserInput())}
```

So `e` in the function is undefined. You need to change it to pass the `event`

```
onChange={(e)=>this.props.updateInput(this.handleUserInput(e))}
```